clickhouse support for using azure blob storage as cold disk ( does the performance of this match with aws s3 as cold disk )
clickhouse to use azure blob storage as disk will this configuration where type is azure_blob_storage, is this still the case where performance of this type isn't matched when used with type as s3 for aws, accordingly to this artical https://engineering.contentsquare.com/2023/clickhouse-on-azure/ it is recommended to use s3proxy with azure blob storage.
As azure provides CSI plugin to blob storage using this configuration where the blob storage can be mounted on the pod when running in AKS, will this helps to acheive the same performance when used type as s3 on aws
We are going to go the mode to use s3proxy on azure to use blob storage as disk for tierign the data, we want to confirm the approach to avoid s3proxy if we can

I would suggest to test on your setting by yourself, because different workloads (query types) can result in different results, not mention different disks and network io settings.

CSI with azure blobstore will not work as local disk,  with clickhouse
try add local cache disk to improve performance
